# Can a team that uses Scrum achieve Co-Dev and domain expertise if it handles many SW domains?

Tags: agile, scrum

I've worked in a team that developed and gave support for SW practices tools. Those tools were written (and will be written) in many programming languages.

According to Scrum, a given story, **can be implemented by several team members** (according to what I know).

When organized in a team that is oriented to a specific SW domain/framework (.NET for example), this seems possible and even reasonable.

But if your team needs to write in *Python, C#, Java etc.* for several tools, some with different orientation (DB/UI), is this possible? How does the "division of labor" should be made in  this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand the 'all team members' are equal in scrum as an ideal.

Practically, you'll always have people better at some jobs than others. But it's all about reducing the bus factor: voluntarily assigning work to someone who's not the best at it so should a bus happen, or should your expert be overloaded with other things, work can still happen.

The non expert will of course require help/assistance from the expert. But it is better to lower your velocity and take advantage of the help when it is available rather than be stuck when it's not (hospital/overwork case).

Comment: Most of your explanation is focused about why not assigning the most skilled person for a given task, which makes sense but it isn't exactly what I asked. My question was how can a team member become an expert when he isn't focused on a specific domain.

Comment: Yosi: I have no good answer for that one. I *think* that shallower expertise in multiple domains is generally more valuable than very narrow expertise. I also think that (to some extent) shallowness of expertise can be compensated by having multiple pair of eyes to look at a problem. Practically, I think it's ok to have a C# specialist - or Java specialist - in the team, as long as they're training the others and distributing most of the work (and yes, that's going to slow you down). Only a few % of problems require direct application of deep expertise.